# Is it possible to store a UIImage as an userInfo Dictionary?

Tags: swift, uiimage, nsdictionary

How do I store a `UIImage` as an userInfo dictionary of type `[String : UIImage]`.

Comment: How do you mean store it? A `Dictionary` is a key-value pair, what would the keys be, what would the values be?

Comment: Do you mean with a dictionary of type `[String : UIImage]`?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @JAL Yes! Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand.  `["foo" : UIImage()]` or `dict["foo"] = UIImage()` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a UIImage *in* a dictionary as a value, but it wouldn't make a good key. If you want to be able to save it to a plist, you would have to first convert it to into a `Data` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I appreciate it! But I should delete this question from this site. If it's possible, please delete your answer and I'm able to post the new question again. Thanks for your support! Best regards!